# Repeated results from an access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to Access and acually to db's ,

I'm trying to perform a db for recording the results of a really huge survey. So far everything is ok but now that i am designing the Queries I am getting repeated results and I don't know why.

My SQL Statement is:

```
SELECT T_VALORACIO.IdValoracio, T_ENQUESTA.Treballador, 
T_VALORACIO.IdValPreu
FROM (T_ALSECA INNER JOIN T_VALORACIO ON T_ALSECA.idTipus = 
T_VALORACIO.idTipus) INNER JOIN T_ENQUESTA ON T_ALSECA.IdAlseca =  
T_ENQUESTA.idAlSeca
WHERE (((T_ENQUESTA.Treballador)=True) AND ((T_VALORACIO.IdValPreu)=4));
```

I would expect getting  the results that fit both cases, but the results that fit just the first case are also shown.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What do you mean by saying "get the results that just fit the first case"? Do you mean that you get results with `T_ENQUESTA.Treballador = True` but `T_VALORACIO.IdValPreu != 4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
```

This removes duplicate rows.

Comment: Just what I needed :-)

Comment: Distinct is your friend! Glad I could help.